# I want to get required documents but it seems to return every document of the collection

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to display the data with category doctor but I seem to get all the data.

I have tried using: result=db.find({},{"first_name": 1, "last_name": 1, "cat": 'doctor'}) but still I get the wrong result.

```
@app.route("/users/get_doctors", methods = ['GET'])
def get_doctors():
    try:
        db = mongo.db.Login_Details
        result=db.find({},{"first_name": 1, "last_name": 1, "cat": 
        'doctor'})
        doctors = []
        for dr in result:
            doctors.append({"first_name": dr['first_name'], "last_name" : 
            dr['last_name'], "cat" : dr['cat']})
        return jsonify(doctors)
    except Exception:
        return 'error'
```

Comment: I think you're passing an empty dict (i.e. {}) to the find method

Comment: I have tried this
result = db.find({'cat': 'doctor'}, ['first_name', 'last_name', 'cat']) 
and
also this
result = db.find({'cat': 'doctor'}, {'first_name', 'last_name', 'cat'})
but, still not working

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to combine `filter` and `projection` which is incorrect. Per [MongoDB docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) the first argument is `filter` and the second one is `projection` (which you may or may not need).

```
# Thi result contain all document with category doctor. Only first name,
# last name and category are retrieved.
result = db.find({'cat': 'doctor'}, ['first_name', 'last_name', 'cat'])
```

The above example takes two arguments: the first one is a `filter` which is something like `WHERE` clausule in an ordinary SQL and the second argument is `projection` which lists fields which are going to be retrieved.

Comment: I have tried it but there seems to be some syntax issue I believe due to which it does not work.

Comment: I've fixed a typo in the code sample (dp -> db). It should work now.

Comment: There seems to be some other problem other than this. I have fixed the typo already in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.find( {"cat" : "doctor" })
```

Will find all documents with cat = doctor.

```
db.find({"cat": "doctor"}, {"first_name": 1, "last_name": 1})
```

Will find all documents with cat = doctor. It will then only output the `first_name` and `last_name` fields. It will also output the `_id` field unless this explicitly suppressed by  `{ "_id": 0, "first_name": 1, "last_name": 1}`. The second argument defines the projection of the fields i.e. what fields will appear in the output.

See [mongodb find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) for details on the syntax for queries and projections.